# mysql order by with same date but id's are flipped

Tags: mysql

When i get rows from the db with the same exact same date's but the id's get fillped as such:

```
select * from rent ORDER BY date_at ASC;
id: 70 date: 12-01-2013
id: 69 date: 12-01-2013
```

Is there a way to work around this so that i can sort by date but still retain the id order if the date's are the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another column you want to sort by in the `order` condition

```
SELECT * FROM rent 
ORDER BY date_at ASC,
         id ASC
```